What do you think about the following MO question?
What do you think about the following MO question?
By posting this question for feedback I am following David Roberts' very patient and kind advice.
If you have already seen the question below please don't skip to read the italicized text below.
"What are some theorems by deceased or retired authors published in peer reviewed journals or otherwise reputable sources that are widely accepted to be true but that you happen to know are actually false?
I am guessing we all encounter this from time to time, but there is no appropriate place to share them. Slowly but surely the mathematical literature is becoming a minefield if we all keep this information to ourselves.
I will start with sharing an example. It concerns homotopy invariance of the Leray-Schauder fixed point index for compact and compactly fixed maps which I explained in detail here.
Thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge!
Note 1: the above question is different from this question which concerns results that are currently widely accepted to be false.
Note 2: if the author is not deceased or retired then this question has some suggestions of how one could handle it."
Please allow me a few words to explain why this is important to me. Firstly, it may be relevant to know that I am autistic and I have great difficulty understanding other people's feelings. Truth and Mathematics are my main focus in life. None of this is aimed at anyone personally. I am not at all trying to be mean or anything, quite the opposite. I have experienced a lot of suffering myself because of mistakes in the mathematical literature. For example, by thinking for several weeks that I had made a huge breakthrough only to be disappointed later when I found out that a certain theorem I used was false. I was actually lucky that I hadn't made my work public yet, I can't imagine the pain, stigma and public humiliation if I had made my work public. It is therefore my sincere belief that the above question will actually reduce the total amount of suffering by mathematicians in the world. Sure, some retired mathematicians will be disappointed if they find out that some part of their work is wrong, but the suffering will end there and not propagate further to future mathematicians. As a serious mathematician, is it really better to die without knowing the truth? If you reap what you sow, if there is a law of karma, then it is only in your best interest that your mistakes are corrected quickly and don't propagate and become the reason for further suffering in the world. Your own total suffering would only increase then. May the truth set us free.

Thanks for following through in this. I will note that such a question will be tagged [big-list] and be Community Wiki'ed. Note that we use CW differently here on MathOverflow compared to the rest of StackExchange: it has come to roughly mean that there can never be just a single correct answer.

Linking to or acknowledging https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31337/how-do-i-fix-someones-published-error in some way might be a good idea.

@DavidRoberts I have edited the question with your link. I hope it is ok like this.

This question might be opinion based.

I am skeptical of the value of this question.  There are many, many thousands of papers in the literature, spread over a vast range of fields.  I would not be surprised if 2%-3% of them were false.  A MO question is just not a good way to collect and curate this vast amount of information, especially since typically only a tiny number of people can judge the correctness of any particular paper.
I understand your frustration with the literature, but really the only way to be certain that a paper is correct is to read it yourself.  Things that are widely accepted (meaning cited and used by many current researchers) are generally trustworthy, but if you find an obscure paper that no one knows about that is important for your research, then you just have to work through it yourself.
Let me now offer some semi-solicited life advice.  I will assume that you’re working on normal mathematics; if instead you think you have solved a famous problem like the Riemann hypothesis, then unless you already have a track record of solving ordinary problems people will basically ignore you since the internet is littered with such claims (and indeed, the chance that you haven’t made some kind of error is close to zero).
That being said, I think that you dramatically overstate the consequences of making a mistake, and do so in a way that is psychologically damaging for someone interested in research.  I have seen plenty of people (including myself) make mistakes, and I have not seen them experience “pain, stigma and public humiliation”.  Really, people are mostly pretty generous, especially if the only error is relying on another paper that had a mistake.
To share a personal story, my PhD thesis (published in GAFA with two very thorough referee reports, one that was 18 pages long and one that was 9 pages long) has a serious mistake in it.  The main theorem in it is true as stated, but one of the intermediate lemmas is simply wrong.  Once I learned about this (several years after publishing it), I immediately knew several ways around the error, but had moved on to other things.  Since one way of fixing it would lead to some other nice consequences, I lectured about this and included that particular approach in several well-publicized problems list.  This led to a lot of work on related problems, and a fix appeared in the recent paper here.  Once that appears, I will publish an erratum pointing to it and also giving another argument.
The purpose of sharing this is to illustrate that errors are a normal part of life, and that as long as you acknowledge them they’re often not as big a deal as they appear when you’re younger.

One thing I might add is that for articles by deceased authors, to claim that people generally don't know about the mistake is a bold claim. If the results are used at all, then for papers that old, someone will have noticed the mistake and addressed it somewhere, or else people have just stopped using the result as it is unreliable. To justify a claimed of a hitherto unknown error in a paper one should track through the citations to the paper and double check it hasn't been pointed out before.
